# Raised border in Python GObject Gtk

Tags: python, gtk3, gobject

I've found that the [Gtk.BorderStyle](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/enums.html#Gtk.BorderStyle) enum gives you some options as to border (raised, sunken, etc.). How do you actually apply these settings to a Gtk.Widget?

Answer (score 0):

These are set in CSS, using `border-style` and related CSS properties. For example:

```
button {
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

See https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-properties.html for more information.